# C++ enum class quint64 type

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I have following `enum class`:

```
#ifndef UEPROTOCOLCOMMANDS_H
#define UEPROTOCOLCOMMANDS_H

enum class UeProcotolCommand
{
    INVALID_COMMAND=0x0000000000000000,

    SERVER_GET_CLIENTS_VERSIONS=0x0000000000000001,
    SERVER_CONNECTION_RESET=0x0000000000000002,

    CLIENT_GET_DATABASE_CREDENTIALS=0x1000000000000001,
    CLIENT_DISCOVER_COMM_SERVER=0x1000000000000002
};   // UeProtocolCommands

#endif // UEPROTOCOLCOMMANDS_H
```

and it generates following error:

```
In file included from ../../../../uePOSCommProtocol/net/comm_protocol/uemessageheader.h:6:0,
                 from ../../../../uePOSCommProtocol/net/comm_protocol/uemessagerequest.h:6,
                 from ../../../../uePOSCommProtocol/ueposcommprotocol.h:8,
                 from ../../../uemainwindow.h:16,
                 from ../../../main.cpp:3:
../../../../uePOSCommProtocol/net/comm_protocol/ueprotocolcommands.h:11:37: error: enumerator value 1152921504606846977l is too large for underlying type 'int'
     CLIENT_GET_DATABASE_CREDENTIALS=0x1000000000000001,
                                     ^
../../../../uePOSCommProtocol/net/comm_protocol/ueprotocolcommands.h:12:33: error: enumerator value 1152921504606846978l is too large for underlying type 'int'
     CLIENT_DISCOVER_COMM_SERVER=0x1000000000000002
                                 ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
14:23:40: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project uePOSCommClient (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

I need to tell to compiler that enum elements are of type `quint64`, not the default `int`. How?

Comment: Sorry, my search was baad! Can someone delete question?

Comment: If you use `enum UeProtocolCommand` then it will select a type that can fit all the enumerators.  But if you use `enum class` then it is up to you to manually select the type  (it defaults to `int`, does not deduce a type based on enumerators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enum class : quin64 { ... }` (see [enumeration declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)). So the complete definition should be:

```
enum class UeProcotolCommand : quint64
{
    INVALID_COMMAND=0x0000000000000000,

    SERVER_GET_CLIENTS_VERSIONS=0x0000000000000001,
    SERVER_CONNECTION_RESET=0x0000000000000002,

    CLIENT_GET_DATABASE_CREDENTIALS=0x1000000000000001,
    CLIENT_DISCOVER_COMM_SERVER=0x1000000000000002
};   // UeProtocolCommands
```